# miktex refuses to work – I believe due to access being denied

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I will add a few images of all things that I believe to be related to the problem.
I am a new user of miktex and I can't get it to work. I am attempting to run figure 1.1 from the not so short interdaction to LaTeX 2. The only things I did to the miktex software is update, I did not touch the settings.
Also when I try a different program, I get the error message ‘can't write on untitled-1.png’ and asks me for a different file to write on
[image]

[image]

note: the untitled-1.log is empty

consule output:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1) entering
> extended mode (C:/Users/user/Documents/untitled-1.tex LaTeX2e
> <2020-10-01> patch level 4 L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse
> <2020-03-03>
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
> Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdft
> ex.def) (C:/Users/user/Documents\untitled-1.aux)
> [1{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local /MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
> (untitled-1.aux) )<C:/Users/user/AppData/Loc
> al/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb> Output
> written on untitled-1.pdf (1 page, 12786 bytes). SyncTeX written on
> untitled-1.synctex.gz. Transcript written on untitled-1.log. This is
> pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1) entering extended
> mode (C:/Users/user/Documents/untitled-1.tex LaTeX2e <2020-10-01>
> patch level 4 L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
> Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdft
> ex.def) (untitled-1.aux)
> [1{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pd ftex.map}]
> (untitled-1.aux) )<C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts
> /type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb> Output written on untitled-1.pdf
> (1 page, 12786 bytes). SyncTeX written on untitled-1.synctex.gz.
> Transcript written on untitled-1.log.
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log

pdflatex attempt:

[image]

the pdf file properties:

[image]

Comment: The standard question: Is your miktex up to date? Additionally please post the full contens of the log file not a picture as in the first image. We can deduce a lot from the full log file.

Comment: as i said the .log is empty but i added the consule output.
i think it may be empty becouse of the same prammision issue

Comment: That sounds rather strange. It should not print to console and not also add stuff to the log. Do you mind compiling this with straight `pdflatex` such that we don't have to deal with what ever `texify` is doing

Comment: ok i added it hope this helps
btw this is what gave me the idea that it has to do with pramissions (i couldnt find anything to help on the internet) oh and giving it more pdf files doesnt help (the thing is my computer registers pdfs as chrome html documents with chrome icons and not like a adobe file or anything of the sort)

Comment: hm, why you have an untitled-1.pdf.pdf with two pdf at the end? This looks quite odd. Try to delete this or rename the tex-file so that wrong pdf not longer interferes. And don't use texify, at least not while still learning. (Side remark:  ensure that you can see all file extensions, don't let windows hide some from you).

Comment: ooh that i named it pdf in order to crate it the computer added another .pdf for so e reason

Comment: wait i changed the actove pdf to .pdf.pdf and it worked

Comment: how weird well thank u(btw i too a loo at ur profile and well congrats dude thats awsome and very impresive i hope to be that useful one day)

Comment: o so i tried removing the extra pdf and it says that it already exists whicch is hella weird

Comment: hey quick question how do i mark this answered

Comment: if u could make an answer ill approve it as soon as i can